# How to print in a single line in R language

Tags: r

I was doing some HandOn in R:

```
toppers <- sample(80:100, 5)
s <- ifelse(toppers>90,"best class", "needs improvement")
```

I need to print s in a single line. How can I do?

Actual:

```
[1] "best class"        "needs improvement" "needs improvement"
[4] "needs improvement" "needs improvement"
```

Expected:

```
[1] "best class"        "needs improvement" "needs improvement"  "needs improvement" "needs improvement"
```

Comment: `print(s) ` gives the output as you specify

Comment: The printing simply matches the width of your display. If you want them combined, try `paste(s, collapse = ' ')`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @C.Braun.
Tjhe output is :

`
"needs improvement needs improvement best class needs improvement best class"
`

I need inverted commas (") as well. As I was doing some test and it is not passing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "Expected" output is ambiguous, so I will give various answers to cover all the bases.

First, if you are only interested in getting that exact format in an interactive session, you can simply tell R to use a larger line width so that it doesn't wrap:

```
> options(width=9999)
```

After calling that, objects printed by the default read-eval-print loop will display on a single line until they reach a length of 9999:

```
> s
[1] "needs improvement" "needs improvement" "needs improvement" "best class"        "needs improvement"
```

Another approach, if you simply want to print the list to console stdout without any formatting, is to use `cat()`. `cat()` prints directly to the console or a file without much conversion.

```
> cat(s)
needs improvement needs improvement needs improvement best class needs improvement
```

You'll note that removes quotes. If you want to preserve quotes around each string in the output, we can use `deparse()`. We'll also use `sapply()` to deparse each string separately, otherwise it will put an unwanted `c()` around the whole thing:

```
> cat(sapply(s, function(word) deparse(word)), collapse=' ')
"needs improvement" "needs improvement" "needs improvement" "best class" "needs improvement"
```

The above still prints directly to console stdout. If you want to save the combined string in a variable, we can use `paste0()` instead of `cat()`:

```
> x <- paste0(sapply(s, function(word) deparse(word)), collapse=' ')
> cat(x)
"needs improvement" "needs improvement" "needs improvement" "best class" "needs improvement"
```